# Limit button width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Below is a part of the code that displays the buttons below the body.

```
  ......
                Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("One button"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    //space between button
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("Two button"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
 ......
```

But the problem is that the width of the buttons is obtained for the entire page. And I would like it to be limited to the width of the body `BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800)`.

In the photo, I marked the desired width of the buttons with red borders.
How can I achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap full button widget with `ConstrainedBox`.

```dart
  ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 800),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("One button"),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  //space between button
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("Two button"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

If you like to avoid padding, you can remove it or use `ConstrainedBox` on `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add 2 Expanded Widgets and use the `flex` property. [Expanded, flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html)

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 40,
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("One button"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    //space between button
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 40,
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text("Two button"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 10,
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```